# Echo Array Values in Comma Separated List

Tags: php, arrays, loops, oop, foreach

I am selecting values from my database, when I dump the `$results` I get;

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'FieldName' => 'certification_name',
     'FieldValue' => 'White Belt',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'FieldName' => 'certification_name',
     'FieldValue' => 'Yellow Belt',
  ),
)
```

I want to display the following on my page;

> Certification List: White Belt, Yellow Belt

I have created a loop but when I `echo` the result I get this;

```
Certification List: Array Array
```

My PHP code;

```
foreach ($results as $result) {

    $name = $result->FieldName;
    $value = $result->FieldValue;

    $items[] = array(
        'name' => $name, 
        'value' => $value
    );
}

$items = implode("\n", $items);
echo 'Certification List: ' .$items;
```

What do I need to change in order to get this working?

Comment: Can't you do it by just using `$items[] = $result->FieldValue;`

Comment: If you don't do anything else with the data, you could also look into the MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) so that you don't have to process the result set at all.

Comment: Are you using PDO or MySQLi? If it's PDO, you can use the fetch argument `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` in your [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and it will return the values in the way you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't push arrays into `$items`, just push the values.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $items[] = $result->FieldValue;
}
$item_list = implode(", ", $items);
echo "Certification List: $item_list";
```

You can also replace the loop with:

```
$items = array_column($results, 'FieldValue');
```